# Correcting timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a scaffold. There I notice that the published_at component is 1 hour behind.
The component displayed 2012-May 8 13-34 when it's supposed to be an hour ahead.

In sqlite, the published_at time is shown as 2012-05-08 19:34:00.000000.
Also the created_at and up_dated_at are off as well.
created_at: 2012-05-08 18:34:02.795241
updated_at: 2012-05-08 18:34:02.795241

I've  been searching but I'm not finding anything solid to a solution.
How can I correct these issues so that the values are entered in correctly?

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rails always stores the UTC timezone in the database. Whenever you display one of these times in your app, they are converted relative to your timezone before being displayed. Perhaps your timezone is configured incorrectly.

Make sure you have `config.time_zone` set properly. You can use `rake time:zones:local` to find a timezone value you can use in your config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris My configs: config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' config.active_record.default_timezone = :local When I run rails time:zone:local * UTC -05:00 * Bogota Eastern Time (US & Canada) Indiana (East) Lima Quito But I'm still experiencing the incorrect time issue.